# @EmbeddedId casuses additional selects when i use left join fetch

Tags: hibernate, select

I want to fetch CrpEntity with UmowaEntity and hibernate generate additional selects.

Dao:

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM UmowaEntity u "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.jednostkaRozliczeniowa jr "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.kartyPracy kp "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.crpy crpy "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH crpy.pk.crp crp "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.mpki mpki "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH u.umowaRozliczenia ur "
        + "WHERE u.uzytkownik= :uzytkownik"
        + "AND u.aktywna = 'true'")
public List<UmowaEntity> findUmowyByZleceniobiorcaAndUmowaAktywna(UzytkownikEntity uzytkownik);
```

Genereted SQL:

```
Hibernate: select distinct umowaentit0_.id as id1_10_0_, jednostkar1_.id as id1_3_1_, kartypracy2_.id as id1_4_2_, 
crpy3_.crp_id as crp_id3_11_3_, crpy3_.umowa_id as umowa_id2_11_3_, crpentity4_.id as id1_1_4_, 
mpki5_.mpk_id as mpk_id2_12_5_, mpki5_.umowa_id as umowa_id3_12_5_,
umowarozli6_.id as id1_13_6_, umowaentit0_.aktywna as aktywna2_10_0_, 
umowaentit0_.data_obowiazywania_do as data_obo3_10_0_, umowaentit0_.data_obowiazywania_od as data_obo4_10_0_, umowaentit0_.data_rozpoczecia_aneksu as data_roz5_10_0_, 
umowaentit0_.data_zamkniecia as data_zam6_10_0_, umowaentit0_.jednostka_rozliczeniowa as jednost12_10_0_, umowaentit0_.max_liczba_godzin as max_licz7_10_0_, 
umowaentit0_.numer as numer8_10_0_, umowaentit0_.prefinansowanie as prefinan9_10_0_, umowaentit0_.przedmiot as przedmi10_10_0_, umowaentit0_.rodzaj as rodzaj11_10_0_, 
umowaentit0_.zleceniobiorca as zleceni13_10_0_, jednostkar1_.rodzaj_jednostki_rozliczeniowej as rodzaj_j2_3_1_, kartypracy2_.data_modyfikacji as data_mod2_4_2_, 
kartypracy2_.data_wprowadzenia as data_wpr3_4_2_, kartypracy2_.uuid as uuid4_4_2_, kartypracy2_.wersja as wersja5_4_2_, kartypracy2_.crp_id as crp_id10_4_2_, 
kartypracy2_.data_karty_pracy as data_kar6_4_2_, kartypracy2_.ilosc_minut as ilosc_mi7_4_2_, kartypracy2_.ilosc_wykonanych_jednostek as ilosc_wy8_4_2_, 
kartypracy2_.mpk_id as mpk_id11_4_2_, kartypracy2_.status as status9_4_2_, kartypracy2_.umowa_id as umowa_i12_4_2_, kartypracy2_.umowa_id as umowa_i12_4_0__, 
kartypracy2_.id as id1_4_0__, crpy3_.aktywny as aktywny1_11_3_, crpy3_.umowa_id as umowa_id2_11_1__, crpy3_.crp_id as crp_id3_11_1__, crpentity4_.archiwalny as archiwal2_1_4_, 
crpentity4_.mpk_id as mpk_id5_1_4_, crpentity4_.nazwa_skrocona as nazwa_sk3_1_4_, crpentity4_.nr_crp as nr_crp4_1_4_, mpki5_.aktywny as aktywny1_12_5_, 
mpki5_.umowa_id as umowa_id3_12_2__, mpki5_.mpk_id as mpk_id2_12_2__, umowarozli6_.data_modyfikacji as data_mod2_13_6_, umowarozli6_.data_wprowadzenia as data_wpr3_13_6_, 
umowarozli6_.uuid as uuid4_13_6_, umowarozli6_.wersja as wersja5_13_6_, umowarozli6_.crp_id as crp_id11_13_6_, umowarozli6_.ilosc_minut as ilosc_mi6_13_6_, 
umowarozli6_.ilosc_wykonanych_jednostek as ilosc_wy7_13_6_, umowarozli6_.mpk_id as mpk_id12_13_6_, umowarozli6_.okres_rozliczenia_do as okres_ro8_13_6_, 
umowarozli6_.okres_rozliczenia_od as okres_ro9_13_6_, umowarozli6_.status as status10_13_6_, umowarozli6_.umowa_id as umowa_i13_13_6_, 
umowarozli6_.umowa_id as umowa_i13_13_3__, umowarozli6_.id as id1_13_3__ from umowa umowaentit0_ 
left outer join jednostka_rozliczeniowa jednostkar1_ on umowaentit0_.jednostka_rozliczeniowa=jednostkar1_.id 
left outer join karta_pracy kartypracy2_ on umowaentit0_.id=kartypracy2_.umowa_id 
left outer join umowa_crp crpy3_ on umowaentit0_.id=crpy3_.umowa_id 
left outer join crp crpentity4_ on crpy3_.crp_id=crpentity4_.id 
left outer join umowa_mpk mpki5_ on umowaentit0_.id=mpki5_.umowa_id 
left outer join umowa_rozliczenie umowarozli6_ on umowaentit0_.id=umowarozli6_.umowa_id where umowaentit0_.zleceniobiorca=? and umowaentit0_.aktywna='true'
```

If UmowaEntity has two CrpEntities hibernate generate 3 additional selects (select umowaentity and two select crpentity). "LEFT JOIN FETCH crpy.pk.crp crp" doesn't fetch properly CrpEntities:

```
Hibernate: select crpentity0_.id as id1_1_0_, crpentity0_.archiwalny as archiwal2_1_0_, crpentity0_.mpk_id as mpk_id5_1_0_, crpentity0_.nazwa_skrocona as nazwa_sk3_1_0_, crpentity0_.nr_crp as nr_crp4_1_0_ from crp crpentity0_ where crpentity0_.id=?
Hibernate: select umowaentit0_.id as id1_10_0_, umowaentit0_.aktywna as aktywna2_10_0_, umowaentit0_.data_obowiazywania_do as data_obo3_10_0_, umowaentit0_.data_obowiazywania_od as data_obo4_10_0_, umowaentit0_.data_rozpoczecia_aneksu as data_roz5_10_0_, umowaentit0_.data_zamkniecia as data_zam6_10_0_, umowaentit0_.jednostka_rozliczeniowa as jednost12_10_0_, umowaentit0_.max_liczba_godzin as max_licz7_10_0_, umowaentit0_.numer as numer8_10_0_, umowaentit0_.prefinansowanie as prefinan9_10_0_, umowaentit0_.przedmiot as przedmi10_10_0_, umowaentit0_.rodzaj as rodzaj11_10_0_, umowaentit0_.zleceniobiorca as zleceni13_10_0_ from umowa umowaentit0_ where umowaentit0_.id=?
Hibernate: select crpentity0_.id as id1_1_0_, crpentity0_.archiwalny as archiwal2_1_0_, crpentity0_.mpk_id as mpk_id5_1_0_, crpentity0_.nazwa_skrocona as nazwa_sk3_1_0_, crpentity0_.nr_crp as nr_crp4_1_0_ from crp crpentity0_ where crpentity0_.id=?
```

Entities:

UmowaEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "umowa")
public class UmowaEntity implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private Set<UmowaCrpEntity> crpy = new HashSet<>();
...

public UmowaEntity() {
}

@Id
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.umowa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<UmowaCrpEntity> getCrpy() {
    return crpy;
}

public void setCrpy(Set<UmowaCrpEntity> crpy) {
    this.crpy = crpy;
}
```

CrpEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "crp")
public class CrpEntity implements Serializable {

private Long id;
private Set<UmowaCrpEntity> umowy = new HashSet<>();
...

public CrpEntity() {
}

@Id
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.crp", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<UmowaCrpEntity> getUmowy() {
    return umowy;
}

public void setUmowy(Set<UmowaCrpEntity> umowy) {
    this.umowy = umowy;
}
```

UmowaCrpEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "umowa_crp")
@AssociationOverrides({
  @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.umowa",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "umowa_id")),
  @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.crp",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "crp_id"))})
public class UmowaCrpEntity implements Serializable {

private UmowaCrpId pk = new UmowaCrpId();
private Boolean aktywny = Boolean.TRUE;

public UmowaCrpEntity() {
}

@EmbeddedId
public UmowaCrpId getPk() {
    return pk;
}

public void setPk(UmowaCrpId pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
}

@Transient
public UmowaEntity getUmowa() {
    return getPk().getUmowa();
}

public void setUmowa(UmowaEntity umowa) {
    getPk().setUmowa(umowa);
}

@Transient
@JsonView(UmowaView.Lista.class)
public CrpEntity getCrp() {
    return getPk().getCrp();
}

public void setCrp(CrpEntity crp) {
    getPk().setCrp(crp);
}

@JsonView(ViewAlways.class)
public Boolean getAktywny() {
    return aktywny;
}

public void setAktywny(Boolean aktywny) {
    this.aktywny = aktywny;
}
```

UmowaCrpId:

```
@Embeddable
public class UmowaCrpId implements Serializable {

private UmowaEntity umowa;
private CrpEntity crp;

@ManyToOne
public UmowaEntity getUmowa() {
    return umowa;
}

public void setUmowa(UmowaEntity umowa) {
    this.umowa = umowa;
}

@ManyToOne
public CrpEntity getCrp() {
    return crp;
}

public void setCrp(CrpEntity crp) {
    this.crp = crp;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.umowa);
    hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.crp);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final UmowaCrpId other = (UmowaCrpId) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.umowa, other.umowa)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.crp, other.crp)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the problem appears when i want to fetch CrpEntity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use associations in embedded ids. This is a known issue. You can map the simple columns in the embedded id and map the association with `insertable = false, updatable = false` in the entity if you need to.